# Android BaseAdapter slow in scrolling

Tags: android, video, scroll, baseadapter

I'm listing video from device memory with a **BaseAdapter** and I've noticed that scrolling is not very performing, very slow.
Should I use a different method to do this work or is there a way to improve this one ?

```
public class StoredVideo extends Activity {

   public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "it.mypackage.com";
   private Cursor videocursor;
   private int video_column_index;
   ListView videolist;
   int count;
    String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID };

   private String thumbPath;
   SharedPreferences pref;
   String account;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videomain);
    pref = getSharedPreferences("AppPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    init_phone_video_grid();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void init_phone_video_grid() {

    System.gc();
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };

    String orderBy = android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;

    videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            proj, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

    count = videocursor.getCount();
    videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneVideoList);
    videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
    videolist.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);


    videolist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
                return onLongListItemClick(v, pos, id);
        }
        protected boolean onLongListItemClick(View v, final int pos, long id) {

            final String str= videolist.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick stirng=" + str);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  
                        AlertDialog.Builder(StoredVideo.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this video ?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                if(videocursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                    videocursor.moveToPosition(pos);
                                    video_column_index = videocursor
                                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);

                                String filename = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);

                                removeMedia(filename);
                                videocursor.close();

                                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

                                init_phone_video_grid();    

                                }

                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                               }
                           });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    return true;
                }

            });

}

private OnItemClickListener videogridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        System.gc();
        video_column_index = videocursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String filename = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);

        Log.d("TAGME", filename);

        String videoinfo[] = new String[2];

        int videoId = videocursor.getInt(videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

        Cursor videoThumbnailCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                thumbColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID+ "=" + videoId, null, null);


        if (videoThumbnailCursor.moveToFirst()) {

            thumbPath = videoThumbnailCursor.getString(videoThumbnailCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA));
            Log.d("ThumbPath: ",thumbPath);

        }

        videoinfo[0] = filename;
        videoinfo[1] = thumbPath;

        Intent intent = new Intent(StoredVideo.this, ViewVideo.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, videoinfo);
        StoredVideo.this.startActivity(intent);

    }
};


public void removeMedia(String filename) {

    File  existingFile = new File("\"" + filename + "\"");
    existingFile.delete();
    Toast.makeText(StoredVideo.this, "File " + filename + " deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ContentResolver resolver = StoredVideo.this.getContentResolver();
    resolver.delete(Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Video.Media.DATA + "=?", new String[]{filename});

}

public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context vContext;

    public VideoAdapter(Context c) {
        vContext = c;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public void deleteItem(int position) {

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.gc();
        ViewHolder holder;
        String id = null;
        convertView = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(vContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.thumbImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

            video_column_index = videocursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
            id = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
            video_column_index = videocursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
            videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
            holder.txtTitle.setText(id);
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?",
                    new String[] { id }, null);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            long ids = cursor.getLong(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

            ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    crThumb, ids, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                    options);
            holder.thumbImage.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
            curThumb = null;


            } 

        } 
        return convertView;
    }
}


static class ViewHolder {

    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtSize;
    ImageView thumbImage;
}
```

}

Comment: first, don't use a managedQuery when you are only using the cursor to get a single value. then, close the cursor when you don't need it. then, the very fact of using a query to get each id is bound to be slow, as you match the name of the video for each video. finally, getting the thumbnail is slow too, you should consider doing that in an asynctask.

Comment: you don't need a new query to get the id, it is already in your `videocursor`.

Comment: also, since you are using a cursor in an adapter, you could use a cursoradapter, which does some of the work for you.

Comment: @njzk2 on which line  I don't need a new query to get the id ?

Comment: in `getView`, instead of a new managedQuery, you can write `long ids = videocursor,getLong(videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));`. Since videocursor already exists and is created only once for the complete list, this should be a significant improvement in terms of speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView Adapter's getView() method will be called numerous times as you scroll the List. So you should not perform any operation that takes more time or more memory. Otherwise bear with slow performance or crash.

Let's see how you can optimize:

**Avoid operations that takes more time or memory**

Do not call managedQuery() from your getView which will affect the performance badly. And you are creating thumbnails there. I wouldn't do that if I need more responsive ListView. If you need them so badly, go for AsyncTask.

**Reuse the View**

The adapters, by default, recycles the views during getView calls to avoid unnecessary object creation. Yikes! Go for it. It's just simple.

```
View v = convertView;

if(v == null) {

   //inflate view

}

// do the rest
```

**Include ViewHolder Patter**

The ViewHolder pattern brings the smoothness into the ListView. If you want sleek scroll, read

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

PS: *The System.gc() call is not the best option to free up memory. Let's see what he Android Doc says,*

System.gc() indicates to the VM that it would be a good time to run the garbage collector. Note that this is a hint only. There is no guarantee that the garbage collector will actually be run.

Comment: Thank you, good suggestions! Do you know how comes that new added video to the gallery appears twice in the list with this method ?

Answer (score 1):

you should not assign every time null to the convertView

```
convertView = null;
if (convertView == null) {
```

remove `convertView = null`. Get rid also of `System.gc();`

Comment: I've just removed the 2 instructions, the strange thing now is that videos are loaded with the same thumbnails. The scrolling is faster, instead.

Comment: You should definitely use a CursorAdapter since you are dealing with a cursor

Comment: It would be better. You are seeing the same thing just because you assign the values to the UI only if convertView == null.